# Qt C++ threads matrix operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, matrix

I am new in C++ and Qt and my mini project as an intern is to make matrix operation with multithreading and I have no idea why my thread does not go and print the add operation result.
I am trying to connect my signal thread.start() to the actually execution function.

```
void MatrixAddition::add (QThread &thread)
    {
        connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(executeAddition()));

    }

    void MatrixAddition::sendMatrix (int m1[100][100], int l1, int c1,
                                                        int m2[100][100], int l2, int c2)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < l1; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < c1; j++)
               matrice1[i][j] = m1[i][j];

       for(int i = 0; i < l2; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < c2; j++)
               matrice2[i][j] = m2[i][j];
    }

    void MatrixAddition::executeAddition ()
    {
    qDebug() << "i am in execute addition";


        for(int i=0; i < linii1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < coloane1; j++)
                matriceRezultat[i][j] = matrice1[i][j] + matrice2[i][j];
        }

        for(int i=0; i < linii1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < coloane1; j++)
                qDebug() << matriceRezultat[i][j];
        }


    }
```

main.cpp

```
addition.sendMatrix(matrix1, linii1, coloane1, matrix2, linii2, coloane2);

    addition.add (thread);
    addition.moveToThread (&thread);
    thread.start ();
```

Comment: Where do you set linii1 and coloane1 values?

Comment: maybe call movetothread before addition.add(thread);

Comment: Please attach code creating threads and addition variable

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. Simply use `QtConcurrent::run` to execute a functor in a thread from the worker pool.

First, let's put your matrix data into a data structure so that it's easy to handle it as one unit:

```
template <int rows, int columns> struct Matrix {
  int data[rows][columns];
  void add(const Matrix & other) {
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
         data[i][j] += other.data[i][j];
  }
};

typedef Matrix<100, 100> Matrix100;
```

Then you can use `QtConcurrent::run` to run the addition in a worker thread, and a `QFutureWatcher` to get informed when the addition is done. Qt 5 and C++11 help us to keep the code concise:

```
QSharedPointer<Matrix100> test() {
  auto watcher = new QFutureWatcher;
  QObject::connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher::finished, [=]{
    qDebug() << "The addition is done";
    watcher->deleteLater();
  });
  QSharedPointer<Matrix100> m1(new Matrix100), m2(new Matrix100);
  // fill the matrices with data here

  QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run([=m1,=m2] { m1->add(*m2); });
  watcher->setFuture(future);
  return m1; // The result will stay alive.
}
```